# Where to find available locale's and their information?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am going to develop a **Number Field** component using jQuery. In that component, I need to find the *thousandSeparator*, *decimalSeparator*, and *decimalPrecision* based on the **user locale** given (like *en-US, de-DE* and etc....). I have tried using *toLocaleString* method but browser compatibility (Safari and IE) is missing. I didn't find any Web Contents containing a list of locales and their information in key-value pairs. Where can I find the same on the website? I don't want to use any external plugins and browser compatibility compromises. Assist me, please...Also, I don't know what are the available locales?

Comment: What do you mean "locale"? Do you want their location or their language?

Comment: I mean language @evolutionxbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unicode Consortium is responsible for updating locale related information. They are maintaining a repository called **Common Locale Data Repository(CLDR)**. We can get the information about available locales and formats used in each locale with the help of their [website](http://cldr.unicode.org/index).